# Determine whether elements of a set are bounded above, below, or to the side of another in 3 or more directions

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm having a difficult time expressing an algorithm mathematically. Assuming a 2D matrix of $x$ and $y$ elements, I have a set of pairs for elements that have been found and definitely exist ($A$), and a set of pairs for elements that may or may not exist ($B$).

From $B$, the elements exist if and only if elements of $A$ lie in 3 or more directions vertically or horizontally. These can be located at infinite depth up, down, left, or right, but not diagonally.

**Example**

In Python, the function determining an element's existence may be written as such:

```
def: exists(x, y, depth):
    found = 0

    # search rightward
    for i in range(depth):
        if x + i < ROWS and elements[x + i][y].found:
            found += 1
            break

    # search leftward
    for i in range(depth):
        if x - i >= 0 and elements[x - i][y].found:
            found += 1
            break

    # search upward
    for i in range(depth):
        if y + i < COLUMNS and elements[x][y + i].found:
            found += 1
            break

    # search downward
    for i in range(depth):
        if y - i >= 0 and elements[x][y - i].found:
            found += 1
            break

    if found >= 3:
        return True
```

**My Attempt**

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets of ordered pairs of natural numbers. Define for any $n = (n_x, n_y) \in B:$

$$A\subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$$
$$B\subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$$

$$f(n) : n \text{ exists}~.$$

$$\forall n \in B: f(n) \Leftrightarrow ~...$$

I get stuck around this point and would really appreciate it if anyone could help me understand how to best translate this.

Thank you,

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using words to describe mathematical ideas. Especially if the idea is more intuitive with words than with symbols. Remember that symbols are abbreviations for concepts, so nothing more than a convenience.

Comment: I agree, good advice. I would like to be able to express ideas with symbols in the most formal way possible simply to learn how things work beyond the simplest expressions - not necessarily to communicate with colleagues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x,y)\in B$ if at least three of the following conditions hold.

1) $\exists (a,b)\in A : a<x$ and $b=y$ 
[There is an ordered pair $(a,b)$ in $A$ such that $(a,b)$ is somewhere to the left of $(x,y)$.]

2) $\exists (a,b)\in A : a=x$ and $b>y$ (Something above)

3) $\exists (a,b)\in A : a>x$ and $b=y$ (Something to the right)

4) $\exists (a,b)\in A : a=x$ and $b<y$ (Something below)

Comment: Interesting! This really makes a lot of sense, but what defines the (a, b) pairs as part of set $B$ and not arbitrary ones? I suppose the universal quantifier mandates this?

Comment: $(a,b)\in A$ and $A\subseteq  \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ so by definition $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers. If for some reason you wanted to emphasize this you would write $(a,b) : a,b\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Ah yes, and of course the only pairs that satisfy the condition are ones in the limited set $B$ - not just any natural number pairs.

Comment: This seems to be saying, "There exists an element $(a,b)$ in $A$, if $a < x$ and $b = y$"? I'm not sure I understand, is $x$ and $y$ any pair in $B$? Could you write it out in words as well so I could perhaps follow it better? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, $(x,y)$ are any pair of natural numbers in B. The colon : doesn’t mean “if”, it means “such that”.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood that $(a,b)$ had to be in $A$. It's still difficult to see where the statement is that says if the condition is met, the element in $B$ is also in $A$. Should it be "$(x,y)\in B \in A$ if at least three of the following conditions hold."?

Comment: I didn’t realize you wanted to add these ordered pairs to $A$ as well because you defined it as a set where the pairs have all already been found. Also, what you’re trying to say should be written as $(x,y)\in B,A$ because $B\in A$ means that $B$ itself is one of the ordered pairs inside $A$.

Comment: Alternatively, you don’t even need to define two sets. Just make one and say $\forall(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$, $(x,y)\in A$ if (not if and only if) the following three conditions hold... And then you could manually define a few initial points. $(a_1,b_1)\in A$, $(a_2,b_2)\in A$ and so on.

Comment: Ah, true, and nothing could technically be added to $A$ anyways I suppose. Although, I suppose our knowledge of $A$ could simply be incomplete, and this tells us which pairs in $B$ are also in $A$.

Comment: I originally used a function to say, it doesn’t necessarily matter what we do with a pair in $b$ that fulfills the requirement, but we ascribe it to the function if and only if it does.